# Scale center on an item in a ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, carousel

I am trying to implement a horizontal carousel, where there will be 3 item at max on the screen and the middle item will have a different view.

I achieved it using the ViewPager by overriding the getPageWidth() callback, but having difficulty in finding the middle item.

Any help or suggestion would be helpful.

```
private class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    public int LOOPS_COUNT = 1000;

    private String[] str = {
            "A",
            "B",
            "C",
            "D",
            "E",
            "F",
            "G",
            "H",
            "I",
            "DD"

    };

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        position = position % str.length;
        return ViewPagerCustomFragment.instance(str[position]);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        return super.instantiateItem(container, position);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return str.length * LOOPS_COUNT; // simulate infinite by big number of products
    }

    @Override
    public float getPageWidth(int position) {
        float f = 1.0f / 3;
        return (f);
    }
}
```

This is my fragment layout...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/abc"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/lin"
        android:text="aaaaaaa"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#000000" />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageview"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/circle" />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageview1"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:src="@drawable/circle"
            android:tint="#000000"/>

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#000000" />
    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that you are swiping through three views at once (since you have three of them on the screen at any time), why don't you try getting the second item of the three items on the screen?

Let's say you have `A`, `B`, and `C` on the screen at any instant. Now, the second item at this moment would be your middle item, i.e. `B`.

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    position = position % str.length;
    if (position % 3 == 0) {
        int mid = position + 1;
        //do what you want to do with this. return a new fragment for the middle item (say ViewPagerCustomFragment2, for example).
        return ViewPagerCustomFragment2.instance(str[mid]);
    } else {
        return ViewPagerCustomFragment.instance(str[position]);
    }
}
```

Comment: No, not necessarily, so basically the viewpager width is divided by 3 and when i scroll it scroll the first item to the left and brings the right one i.e 4th on position 2. This solution will not work in this case.

Comment: then you can simply initialise the mid to 1 (int mid = 1, the initial mid position) and then after every swipe just add 1 to it and change the view.

Comment: Also, what you are trying to do is change the mid view to a different view other than the 2 views on its two sides, right?

Comment: yeah, that would work, but the swipe depends on the users scroll, if the scrolls fast, i.e starting from the extreme right, it swipes 3 views at once and  the new view would be 4,5 and 6th. I was wondering if i could get the position of the extreme left or right view and then i can find the middle view.